# can't find element from popup with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm getting started with selenium and on a test page there is a popup window where I have to fill in my email. The problem is that selenium cant find the element by xpath and it gives me NoSuchElementException.

[I've done a screenshot from the elment here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9sQu.png)

I have tried i with normal findElement()

```
    driver.get("https://phptravels.com/demo/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Main\"]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Main\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[17]/td[1]/span[2]/a")).click();

    Thread.sleep(20000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("test@mail.com");
```

and also with driver.getWindowHandles() but heres the size of windowhandlers alwas 1

```
        driver.get("https://phptravels.com/demo/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Main\"]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Main\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[17]/td[1]/span[2]/a")).click();

    Thread.sleep(20000);
    
    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window

    String subWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String>      handles  = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
   
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("yoyoyo");
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```

any suggestions?

Comment: let me try, please provide the URL

Comment: sure https://phptravels.com/demo/ -> klick on green button pricing -> scroll down and ckick on select. Then the popup will open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop up is in iframe use below code:

Switch using frame id

```
driver.switchTo().frame("pf_582434");
```

Switch using frame index:

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Comment: How can I do it? I can't upvote because I've dont't get 15 upvotes till now